# How to remove the grey out of BootstrapDialog

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I called the following Bootstrap-Dialog:

```
 BootstrapDialog.show({
    title           : $this.text(),
    message     : helptext,
    draggable       : true,
    closeByBackdrop: false,
});
```

Now, it opens the Dialog as i want it, except one fact:

The background, around the dialog is greyed out automatically.
Can I edit this with css, or is there any other way to remove it??

Comment: you can also specify backdrop: 'false' in your javascript code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the modal is openned, the `.modal-backdrop.in` class is added to the parent element.

In your own CSS (that should be import **after** Bootstrap CSS), just add the following line:

```
.modal-backdrop.in {
    opacity; 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. it functions!!